# Extra .html at end of url's in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

We've used the importer from Mage 1 to our new site on Mage 2. All imported products now have an additional .html at the end of the url (mysite.com/myproduct.html.html).

There are over 60,000 of these rewrites in the URL rewrite section of the admin panel. So unfortunately, not something we can tackle one at a time.

Can anyone please suggest a fix for this issue?